# Mysql: Adding product restricted shipping options to cart

Tags: mysql

I have a custom shop, and I need to redo the shipping. However, that is sometimes later, and in the meantime, I need to add a shipping option for when a cart only contains a certain range of products.

SO there is a ship_method table

```
id menuname      name      zone maxweight
1  UK Standard   ukfirst   1    2000
2  UK Economy    uksecond  1    750
3  Worldwide Air world_air 4    2000
```

To this I have added another column prod_restrict which is 0 for the existing ones, and 1 for the restricted ones, and a new table called ship_prod_restrict which contains two columns, ship_method_id and item_id, listing what products are allowed in a shipping category.
So all I need to do is look in my transactions, and for each cart, just check which shipping methods are either prod_restrict of 0 or have 1 and have no products in the cart that aren't in the restriction table.

Unfortunately it seems that because you can't values from an outer query to an inner one, I can't find a neat way of doing it. (edited to show the full query due to comments below)

```
 select ship_method.* from ship_method, ship_prod_restrict where
 ship_method.`zone` = 1 and prod_restrict='0' or
 (
   prod_restrict='1' 
   and ship_method.id = ship_prod_restrict.ship_method_id
   and (
      select count(*) from (
      select transactions.item from transactions 
      LEFT JOIN ship_prod_restrict
      on ship_prod_restrict.item_id = transactions.item 
      and ship_prod_restrict.ship_method_id=XXXXX
      where transactions.session='shoppingcartsessionid'
      and item_id is null
   ) as non_permitted_items < 1 )
 group by ship_method.id
```

gives you a list of whether the section matches or not, and works as an inner query but I can't get that ship_method_id in there (at XXXXX).

Is there a simple way of doing this, or am I going about it the wrong way? I can't currently change the primary shipping table, as this is already in place for now, but the other bits can change. I could also do it within PHP but you know, that seems like cheating!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the count is important, but this might be a bit lighter - hard to tell without a full table schema dump:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.item) FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN ship_prod_restrict r
ON r.item_id = t.item
WHERE t.session = 'foo'
AND r.ship_method_id IN (**restricted, id's, here**)
```

Comment: Have added the rest of the query to see what the count was about. The output needs to be a list of the shipping methods that are valid